# Identifying a transistor marked KS1212T for repair

Tags: power-supply, transistors, identification

I need help identifying a transistor marked KS1212T to repair a power supply.

I have shorted the transistor. Please help me find a replacement part for it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the whole power supply is not fried? If you did not check it and fix the faults and other damage, putting in a new transistor will still blow up.

Comment: There was a short on the board, after removing this transistor short was gone, rest components seem's like ok. Will try to replace the transistor and take a look, if there is no result then the repair makes no sense to me due to non rational costs.

Answer (score 6):

It's a KS1212KA2T from Kwansemi Semiconductor.

Here is the [datasheet](http://www.kwansemi.com/uploadfile/2021/0916/KS1212KA2T.pdf) for the 100V/36A NMOS.

Comment: I have replaced it IRF3710S with similar parameters but the power supply instead of rated 18v has an output of 17v, it holds the load but for some reason has a different voltage((